# an efficient matrix interface in C++

Tags: c++, interface, abstract-class, encapsulation

I am writing a code which uses matrices and advanced operations on them a lot. I am not going to implement a matrix class from the beginning instead I want to have some sort of **Matrix** **abstract class** or **interface** which I define the methods I want for it but it uses another implemented Matrix class through it's core something like:

```
template <typename T>
class IMatrix
{
public:
    /*some methods and also some operator overloads*/
    virtual T operator() (int r, int c)=0;
};
```

as the interface for my matrix class and

```
template <typename T>
class ArdalanMatrix :public IMatrix<T>
{
public:
    ArdalanMatrix(int r,int c, T val=0.){
        numberOfRows = r;
        numberOfColumns = c;
        innerMatrix.resize(r, c, val);
    };
    T operator() (int r, int c) {
        /*implementation*/
    }
private:
    techsoft::matrix<T> innerMatrix;//the inside matrix class 
    int numberOfRows;
    int numberOfColumns;
};
```

I gave you masters an example of what I want to do but I don't know if it is a good approach or a bad one. what do you recommend to me to do these kind of stuff easily?

```
int main() {
    IMatrix<double> *M1 = new ArdalanMatrix<double>(5, 5, 0.);
    IMatrix<double> *M2 = new ArdalanMatrix<double>(5, 5, 0.);
    IMatrix<double> *M3;
    M3 = M1 + M2;//overloaded operator "+"
    M3 = M1 * M2;//overloaded operator "*"
}
```

Comment: It's an opinion but I think it is a bad approach. I don't think there's a good enough abstract interface that can represent a matrix and a useful set of operations (without even going into efficiency considerations). Usually the dimensions of a matrix have a role in the nature of the operations it supports, so a common approach is to use the dimensions in the type, i.e. by making them template parameters.

Comment: I know I had a bad feeling about it either, would you please explain more and give me an example please ?

Comment: There are a few out there. See [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page), [boost.matrix](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/types_overview.html) has a bounded matrix type, [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/), [SMatrix](http://project-mathlibs.web.cern.ch/project-mathlibs/sw/5_16_00/SMatrix/html/) which I worked on a while back, plenty more. This problem has been tackled many times.